# List index out of range that I can't see

Tags: python

I do understand what that error means but can someone explain what am I doing wrong with this particular code? Basically, path = [A,B,C,D] and I am just creating [4][4] (final) 2-dimensional array, that swaps the neighboring indices. The swaping begins with the last element and the element before that and goes to the beginning of the list as loop goes. So at the end I should get [[A,B,D,C][A,C,B,D],[B,A,C,D],[D,B,C,A]]

```
    t = -1
    s = 1
    y = []
    final = []
    path = self.path #path = [A,B,C,D]
    for x in path:
        y.append(path)
        if s < 4:        #Just ensuring to not get out of range
            y[-s],y[-s-1] = y[-s-1],y[-s]
        else:
            y[-1],y[0] = y[0],y[-1]
        final.append(y)
        y = []         # So I won't create multi-dimensional list
```

Error: list index out of range

Comment: When `s = 3`, `-s-1` is -4. `y[-4]` is out of bounds.

Comment: It's already within the first iteration that `y[-s-1]` evaluates to `y[-2]` while `len(y) == 1` so the index is out of range.

Comment: `t` is never used, `s` is always 1 but there's an `if s < 4`, `y` is created empty, then 1 element is added to it, then you attempt to swap 2 of its elements when it only has 1... I recommend a complete rewrite of this, "needlessly complicated" barely even begins to describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that works and is readable:

```
path= ['A','B','C','D']

final= []
for index in range(len(path)):
    row= path[:] # copy the original list
    row[index-1],row[index]= row[index],row[index-1] # swap 2 elements
    final.insert(0, row) # insert at the start so the order is as expected

print(final)
```

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I completely forgot that order does not matter, so it is a very beautiful piece of code you have written, even though it is simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Because here your `y` becomes `[[A, B, C, D]]`not `[A, B, C, D]`. So it has only one element.